# How to get values from a latest id which is similar to another id in mysql

Tags: mysql

My Table is

```
        id  affiliate_id    reset_payment   date
        28  33              14.1            1404212739
        29  33              2               1404212800
        30  35              2               1404212900
```

and i want to get all value which has `affiliate_id` = 33 and This `affiliate_id` 33 should be latest. Here Second Row is my answer.

Comment: WHERE blah blah 33 ORDER BY blah blah blah LIMIT etc

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you don't want do get a million downvotes, please read this - [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) and [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) , and then come back. If you want someone to take time to help you, you should show some level of effort in writing your question. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE affiliate_id = 33
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: not working... it gets first row as answer.. But my answer is 2nd row

Comment: It's ordered by date descending so it gets the latest row for that affiliate_id